# Find a string in a binary file

Tags: python

I am trying to extract data from a binary file where the data chunks are "tagged" with ASCII text. **I need to find the word "tracers" in the binary file so I can read the next 4 bytes (int).**

I am trying to simply loop over the lines, decoding them and checking for the text, which works. But I am having trouble seeking to the correct place in the file directly after the text (the `seek_to_key` function):

```
from io import BytesIO
import struct

binary = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\xd6\x00\x8c<TE\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00tracers\x00\xf2N\x03\x00P\xd9U=6\x1e\x92=\xbe\xa8\x0b<\xb1\x9f\x9f=\xaf%\x82=3\x81|=\xbeM\xb4=\x94\xa7\xa6<\xb9\xbd\xcb=\xba\x18\xc7=\x18?\xca<j\xe37=\xbc\x1cm=\x8a\xa6\xb5=q\xc1\x8f;\xe7\xee\xa0=\xe7\xec\xf7<\xc3\xb8\x8c=\xedw\xae=C$\x84<\x94\x18\x9c=&Tj=\xb3#\xb3=\r\xdd3=\x0eL==4\x00~<\xc6q\x1e=pHw=\xc1\x9a\x92="\x08\x9a=\xe6a\xeb<\xa4#.=\xc4\x0f-=\xa9O\xcb=i\'\x15=\x94\x03\x80=\x8f\xcd\xaf=\xd6\x00\x8c<TE\x9f<m\x9ad<[;Q=\x157X=\x17\xf1u=\xb8(\xa4=\x13\xd3\xfa<\x811_=\xd1iX=Q\x17^;\xd1n\xbe=\xfcb\xcc=\xe8\x9b\x99=W\xa9\x16=\xc5\x83\xa4=\xc0%\x98<\xbb|\x99<>#\x8b:\x1cY\x82;\xb8T\xa4<Cv\x87="n\x1c<J\x152=\x1f\xb2\x9d=&\x18\xb6=\x8a\xf9{=\x0fT\xba=HrX=\xa0\\S=@\xee\xbd=\x1e,\xc5=y\rU<gK\x84=\xe3*\r=\x04\xc4M=\x98a\xb3<\x95 T=\xf2Z\x94=lL\x15=\x07\x1b^=\xf3W\x83<\xf6\xff\xa1<\xb8\xfb\xcb<p\xb4\xd8<\xc9#\xfd<s\xa6\x1f;\xbf7W<\x8a\x9c\x82<\x1c\xb7l=\xa7\xd0\xb7=\xe4\x8d\x97=\xe2\x7f\x82=\x82\xa1\xcc<\xdfs\xca=C\x10p=\xb4\xfa\xb0=\xf35\x87=\x9d\x8bR<d\xb9\x0c<\xb26\xcd=\r\xd5\x1d<\xf4p\xb1=f)\xaf=\xe2M\\=F|\xf9<\x9baW=\x85|\xa3=\x0f\xdd\xa1=\xb6f\xa9=\xcbW\xcf<\xfa\x1a\xbe=\xeb\xda\xb2=\x88\xfb\x8e=\x9f+$=\xbbS\xac;\xa2o\xb5=\x08\xca\xe5<\xc9IC=\xa8\x05\xa6=\xbc \xbd=\x8e\x8d}=U\xcd\xba=\xcbG\x89=}\xadg=Z\xad\x9f=_=\xb6:y\x1c==\xa5\x0b3<<\xe5\x1e=*\xa0\xb6=\n\xcd\xb8\xd9<u\xb5W=rZ\x88=\xe0w}=\xa5\xf0\xa0=\xf4\x91\x82=\xe4r\xc5<\x0e\x91A=Z\x9d-<[N:=\xf1\t\x1e=\xc5_\xc2=\xf8\xea\x98=t\xd7\xbf<~N\xce==@\x93=\x98A\xa7=c\x81x=\xe3\xc6\x94=\xe2&\xcc=\x05\xa9^=\xf7\x05\xa8=[m\x81=\x1b\x0b\x84=\xf5\x98\xb9=+\x90\xd8<\xa2\xcc\xa5=5^\x92=\x0e\x9d\x1d=\x96\xc7\x8b;\xc5E\x9e;r\x1e\xc7=\xea6\xbf=\x19mN;\xd9$D=\x85\xa9\x8b=!\xe9\x90=\xe4/~<\xc1\x9c\xaf=\xde\xe4\x18=e\xb0H=hLO;\x9f\xf8\x8b=p.\xcf=L\x1f\x01<\xea\x19\xaf=Z\xd5\xc2<\xb4\xd8\xcf=s\x84\x0c=\x987\xa5;\x19Z\x93=\x0c\x8fO=y/\x97=\xeaOG=\xb0Fl=\x03\x7f\xbe=\x96\n'

binary_data = BytesIO()
binary_data.write(binary)
binary_data.seek(0)

def seek_to_key(f, line_str, key):
    key_start = line_str.find(key)
    offset = len(line_str[key_start+len(key)].encode('utf-8'))
    f.seek(-offset, 1)

for line in binary_data:
    line_str = line.decode('utf-8', errors='replace')
    print(line_str)
    if 'tracers' in line_str:
        seek_to_key(binary_data, line_str, 'tracers')
        nfloats = struct.unpack('<i', binary_data.read(4))
        print(nfloats)
        break
```

Any recommendations on a better way to do this would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Please explain that in more detail if you want a better answer. What I understand from your current question and code is that you are trying to read the 32-bit number directly after the ASCII text 'tracers'. I'm guessing this is only the first step of your code, since the name `nfloats' suggests that you will be reading a number of floats in the next step ;-) But I'll try to answer this question only.

There are a number of problems with your code:

1. First of all, a simple typo: Instead of `line_str[key_start+len(key)]` you probably meant `line_str[key_start+len(key):]`. (You missed the colon.)
2. You are mixing binary and text data. Why do you decode the binary data as UTF-8? It clearly isn't. You can't just "decode" binary data as UTF-8, slicing a piece of it, and then re-encode that using UTF-8. In this case, the part after your marker is 518 bytes, but when encoded as UTF-8 it becomes 920 bytes. This messes up your offset calculation. Tip: you can search binary data in binary data in Python :-) For example: `b'Hello, world!'.find(b'world')` returns 7. So you don't have to encode/decode the data at all.
3. You are reading line by line. Why is that? Lines are a concept of text files and don't have a real meaning in binary files. It *could* work, but that depends on the file format (which I don't know). In any case, your current code can only find one tracer per line. Is that intentionally, or could there be more markers in each line? Anyway, if the file is small enough to fit in memory, it would be much easier to process the data in one chunk.

A minor note: you could write `binary_data = BytesIO(binary)` and avoid the additional `write()`. Also the `seek(0)` is not necessary.

**Example code**

I think the following code gives the correct result. I hope it will be a useful start to finish your application. Note that this code conforms to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and that all [`pylint`](https://www.pylint.org/) issues were resolved (except for a too long line and missing docstrings).

```py
import io
import struct

DATA = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\xd6\x00\x8c<TE\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00tracers\x00\xf2N\x03\x00P\xd9U=6\x1e\x92=\xbe\xa8\x0b<\xb1\x9f\x9f=\xaf%\x82=3\x81|=\xbeM\xb4=\x94\xa7\xa6<\xb9\xbd\xcb=\xba\x18\xc7=\x18?\xca<j\xe37=\xbc\x1cm=\x8a\xa6\xb5=q\xc1\x8f;\xe7\xee\xa0=\xe7\xec\xf7<\xc3\xb8\x8c=\xedw\xae=C$\x84<\x94\x18\x9c=&Tj=\xb3#\xb3=\r\xdd3=\x0eL==4\x00~<\xc6q\x1e=pHw=\xc1\x9a\x92="\x08\x9a=\xe6a\xeb<\xa4#.=\xc4\x0f-=\xa9O\xcb=i\'\x15=\x94\x03\x80=\x8f\xcd\xaf=\xd6\x00\x8c<TE\x9f<m\x9ad<[;Q=\x157X=\x17\xf1u=\xb8(\xa4=\x13\xd3\xfa<\x811_=\xd1iX=Q\x17^;\xd1n\xbe=\xfcb\xcc=\xe8\x9b\x99=W\xa9\x16=\xc5\x83\xa4=\xc0%\x98<\xbb|\x99<>#\x8b:\x1cY\x82;\xb8T\xa4<Cv\x87="n\x1c<J\x152=\x1f\xb2\x9d=&\x18\xb6=\x8a\xf9{=\x0fT\xba=HrX=\xa0\\S=@\xee\xbd=\x1e,\xc5=y\rU<gK\x84=\xe3*\r=\x04\xc4M=\x98a\xb3<\x95 T=\xf2Z\x94=lL\x15=\x07\x1b^=\xf3W\x83<\xf6\xff\xa1<\xb8\xfb\xcb<p\xb4\xd8<\xc9#\xfd<s\xa6\x1f;\xbf7W<\x8a\x9c\x82<\x1c\xb7l=\xa7\xd0\xb7=\xe4\x8d\x97=\xe2\x7f\x82=\x82\xa1\xcc<\xdfs\xca=C\x10p=\xb4\xfa\xb0=\xf35\x87=\x9d\x8bR<d\xb9\x0c<\xb26\xcd=\r\xd5\x1d<\xf4p\xb1=f)\xaf=\xe2M\\=F|\xf9<\x9baW=\x85|\xa3=\x0f\xdd\xa1=\xb6f\xa9=\xcbW\xcf<\xfa\x1a\xbe=\xeb\xda\xb2=\x88\xfb\x8e=\x9f+$=\xbbS\xac;\xa2o\xb5=\x08\xca\xe5<\xc9IC=\xa8\x05\xa6=\xbc \xbd=\x8e\x8d}=U\xcd\xba=\xcbG\x89=}\xadg=Z\xad\x9f=_=\xb6:y\x1c==\xa5\x0b3<<\xe5\x1e=*\xa0\xb6=\n\xcd\xb8\xd9<u\xb5W=rZ\x88=\xe0w}=\xa5\xf0\xa0=\xf4\x91\x82=\xe4r\xc5<\x0e\x91A=Z\x9d-<[N:=\xf1\t\x1e=\xc5_\xc2=\xf8\xea\x98=t\xd7\xbf<~N\xce==@\x93=\x98A\xa7=c\x81x=\xe3\xc6\x94=\xe2&\xcc=\x05\xa9^=\xf7\x05\xa8=[m\x81=\x1b\x0b\x84=\xf5\x98\xb9=+\x90\xd8<\xa2\xcc\xa5=5^\x92=\x0e\x9d\x1d=\x96\xc7\x8b;\xc5E\x9e;r\x1e\xc7=\xea6\xbf=\x19mN;\xd9$D=\x85\xa9\x8b=!\xe9\x90=\xe4/~<\xc1\x9c\xaf=\xde\xe4\x18=e\xb0H=hLO;\x9f\xf8\x8b=p.\xcf=L\x1f\x01<\xea\x19\xaf=Z\xd5\xc2<\xb4\xd8\xcf=s\x84\x0c=\x987\xa5;\x19Z\x93=\x0c\x8fO=y/\x97=\xeaOG=\xb0Fl=\x03\x7f\xbe=\x96\n'  # noqa


def find_tracers(data):
    start = 0
    while True:
        pos = data.find(b'tracers', start)
        if pos == -1:
            break
        num_floats = struct.unpack('<i', data[pos+7: pos+11])
        print(num_floats)
        start = pos + 11


def main():
    with io.BytesIO(DATA) as file:
        data = file.read()
        find_tracers(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I feel stupid decoding/encoding. Just removing that makes the original code work. There are new lines in the file (200+ MB) for some reason, so I figured I could save some memory by looping over the lines and only extracting the small part of the file that I need.

Comment: @Onlyjus, don't feel stupid. A lot of people are confused about bits & bytes and encodings. I'm glad I could help. NB: Reading a 200 MB binary file into memory is no problem at all, unless you're working on an old memory-limited system of course. I just tested, and loading a 300 MB file into memory using `file.read()` takes 0.15 s on my machine. Searching a (binary) string in that data takes approximately 0.1 s. So no reason to optimize at all. Keep it simple when possible :-) Good luck with your application.